# how to make virtual scroll work with ngFor Directive in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a card that I want repeated, for that I use ngFor, but since I won't know for certain just how many cards I will be repeating, it will vary from load to load, I want to implement virtual scroll to contain a potentially large overflow. The few things I have tried don't work. This is my latest attempt.

```
<ion-content id="content">


   <ion-card id="card" *ngFor="let event of listOfEvents 
     [virtualScroll]="listOfEvents" >          

          <ion-item *virtualItem="let event"> 

       <ion-row>

                <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Guests Needed:</span> {{event.guests}} </ion-col><ion-col><span class="showDetails">Cover:</span> {{event.coverCharge}}</ion-col><ion-col><span class="showDetails">Drink Min:</span>{{event.drinkMin}} </ion-col>

        </ion-row> 

            </ion-item>

         </ion-card>

    </ion-content >
```

Comment: you want virtual scroll to use `ion-card`? or am I misunderstanding..

Comment: @suraj I have an array of cards and I want to contain the potential overflow of cards within virtual scroll..

Comment: right now you seem to be looping the same list twice..you want each item in the list to be a card right?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use `ngFor` along with `[virtualScroll]`. The latter does the looping.

I would try using [`ng-template`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#microsyntax) to set virtual scroll.

```
<ion-content id="content">

 <ng-template [virtualScroll]="listOfEvents">
   <ion-card id="card" *virtualItem="let event" >          
       <ion-row>
          <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Guests Needed:</span> {{event.guests}} </ion-col>
          <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Cover:</span> {{event.coverCharge}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Drink Min:</span>{{event.drinkMin}} </ion-col>
        </ion-row> 
    </ion-card>
 </ng-template> 
</ion-content>
```

Comment: ng-template gives me a terminal error. using template alone didn't give me a terminal error but my page didn't render at all. White screen only. The error indicates I may need to import something to make ng-template work but it doesn't specify.

Comment: I tried it and I'm still only getting white screen. I'm not getting any build errors in the terminal but the page won't render so I don't know how to pin point the error.

Comment: are you sure you are getting the data?

Comment: I may try to figure out how to get ng-template to work.. see what I need to set up for it

Comment: at first I thought the problem was due to empty array so I switched to one I was certain had values and it didn't work.. Is there a plunkr for this anywhere?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/ try the part with `Custom Components`.